# Request url must be str or unicode, got list error?

Tags: python, scrapy, paginator

I am getting following error :  'Request url must be str or unicode, got list'

starting url is 'https://www.zomato.com/istanbul/restaurants?page=1'

```
import scrapy

def parse(self, response):
    all_css = response.css('.search_left_featured')
    all_product = all_css.css('a::attr(href)').extract()

    yield scrapy.Request(all_product, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    max_page_number = 10
    for i in range(1, max_page_number):
        url_next = 'https://www.zomato.com/istanbul/restaurants?page=' + str(i)+''
        yield scrapy.Request(url_next, callback=self.parse)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    items = ZomatodataItem()

    name = response.css('.iNaazl::text').extract()
    genre =response.css('.PhzdX::text').extract()
    location =response.css('.gqeQEx::text').extract()
    tags = response.css('.cunMUz::text').extract()
    address = response.css('.clKRrC::text').extract()
    phone = response.css('.kKemRh::text').extract()

    items['name']= name
    items['genre']= genre
    items['location']= location
    items['tags']= tags
    items['address']= address
    items['phone_number']= phone

    yield items
```

Comment: What line is the error occuring on?

Answer (score 1):

What is your issue? The error seems clear: `.css` returns a `SelectorList`, whose `extract` method returnds a `list`, which you're then passing to `Request` which wants a URL, which a list is not.

Either iterate on your result, or use the (more modern and less confusing) `.get()` and `.getall()` methods from scrapy, `extract()` is deprecated (as in scrapy has stopped using it in its documentation) because it behaves differently depending on being invoked on a Selector (returns a string) or SelectorList (returns a list).

Hell, do both.